# denote by or denote or denote it by

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

It is a bit tricky to use denote in a sentence like this. I am confused, which one of the following is correct? Or if none of them are correct, can you suggest a better way to say this?

> The third reported attack that we denote by the "xyz" attack, occurs
>   when ..

Or

> The third reported attack that we denote the "xyz" attack, occurs
>   when ..

Or

> The third reported attack that we denote it by the "xyz" attack, occurs
>   when ..

By "denote", I mean to "call" it. The "xyz" in my sentence is a name that we created for the attack.

Comment: Two of your three examples are the same, but the last is wrong.

Comment: What do you want *denote* to mean? What definition and usage have you found in a dictionary (there are plenty online)?

Comment: Edited with more clarification on what I mean by `denote`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, to **denote** means to indicate or to convey a meaning. You don't convey a meaning directly; the new term does on your behalf. You bestow the meaning on the new term. You name it or **designate** it. In other words, "The xyz attack" denotes the third reported attack. You designate the third reported attack "the xyz attack."

In addition, to use a restrictive clause (one beginning with "that") implies that there were multiple third reported attacks but that you describe only one as the "xyz" attack. It that's not the case, you should use a non-restrictive clause (one beginning with "which" and enclosed by commas).

Furthermore, it's not clear why the present tense would be used with a single reported attack in the past. Is it possible that one of the following fits the intended meaning? What type of attack occurred, and can it occur more than once?

> The third reported attack, which we designate the "xyz" attack, occurred when (an elderly man was beaten near City Hall)...
>
> The third type of attack, which we designate the "xyz" attack, occurs when (the enemy gains the element of surprise)...
>
> The third type of reported attack, which we designate the "xyz" attack, is associated with (extensive coughing and hoarseness)...

**Edit:** with the clarification that the attack type is a computer attack, the following wording would be appropriate:

> We **call** (or **name** or **designate**) the third type of reported attack a rollback attack.
>
> The third type of reported attack, **termed** (or **called** or **designated**) a rollback attack, ...
>
> "Rollback attack" **denotes** (or **describes** or **refers to**) the third type of reported attack.
>
> The third type of reported attack, which we **call** (or **name** or **designate**) a rollback attack, ...

The phrase "type of reported attack" is used in all cases because only one or several attacks were presumably reported, but you wish to describe all such attacks. The article "a" sounds more natural because you're referring to a general rollback attack. If you later discuss a specific rollback attack, you would use the article "the":

> Consider **a rollback attack** on system X. **This type of attack** affects components Y and Z. **The attack** can be blocked by...

Comment: Thanks. So if I : "The third reported attack that we name it the "xyz" attack, occurs when .. ". Does this seem correct?

Comment: No, that is not correct. I don’t use “that” or “it” in any of my example sentences. I can’t help any more until you clarify what you mean by “attack” and whether the “third reported attack” can occur repeatedly.

Comment: Her is a clarified setenece: "the third reported attack we call the rollback attack, employs a method similar to the one employed in.." Does this seem correct? it is a type of computer attack.

Comment: The name that is given to the attack is from us (the author). So can I say we call?

Comment: Thank you for this clarification; I've edited my answer. I hope this helps.